A puzzle of animals and numbers
This is a group of numbers, that when decoded, gives the story of four animals. You can't really decode the animals, but just note that some of these numbers are corresponded to animals.
21\8\1.\20\7\1.\19\6\1.\18\15\5\1\2,\17\15\4\1\2,\16\15\1\3\1.\14\13\12\11\10\9\8\1\7\2\1\5\2\1\6\2\1\4\2\1\3\1.
A new hint every day to every other day, if I remember.
